# Which scriptures mention the Garbhodakshayi and Karanodakshayi forms of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vishnu, puranas, avatars

I have heard of different forms of Lord Vishnu such as the Garbhodakshayi, Karanodkashayi and Kshirdakashayi forms. I want to know which all Puranas or Vedic scriptures mention these three?

EDIT: 
Some people are commenting that no scriptures mention it from which I guess they mean no Puranas mention it but in that case whichever texts mention these forms please share with references.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28680/which-vishnu-takes-10-avatars-maha-vishnu-or-garbhodakasayi-vishnu-who-is-among

Comment: @AkshayKumarS didnt find the answer there. It only mentions Bhagavtam says this am asking for ALL the scriptures that mention these three.

Comment: No scripture mentions this. Only Gaudiya Vaishnava texts do.

Comment: I want a list of those texts that is why asked the question please share if you know.

Comment: No, Srimad Bhagavatam doesn't mention this. That's Prabhupada's commentary, not the actual Bhagavatam verses.

Answer (score 6):

[Sri Satvata Tantra: Patala One: Avatara - nimitta - kathana](https://archive.org/stream/SriSatvataTantraEnglishTranslation_201804/Sri-Satvata-Tantra-English-Translation#page/n2/mode/1up) mentions these forms:

> [Sri Siva said to Sri Narada]:
>
> 30. Visnu has three forms called purusas. The first, Maha-Visnu, is the creator of the total material energy (mahat), the second is Garbhodasayi, who is situated within each universe, and the third is Ksirodasyi, who lives in the heart of every living being.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing at least one reference! Is this the only text that mentions them? Someone mentioned Gaudiya Vaishnava Texts in the comments above.

Comment: @AmritDhara The thing is all sects don't give equal importance to all texts... They have chosen scriptures based on their philosophy...later people say it's that sect's text... :)

Comment: Ya people seem to have a lot of reservations that way in accepting opposite sects' views even on this site! Please do share any other references you can find then I'll select the answer.

Comment: Btw @AmritDhara Chaitanya Charitamrita also mentions this :)