# Explain the ‘ many Lord Vishnu’s ‘

Tags: vishnu, iconography

[image]

I don’t understand this picture.

From what I have heard,this is a depiction of how innumerable Universes are formed and released from His pores,when the central Lord Vishnu exhales,and return back in Him ,when He inhales.

So then when Lord Vishnu is described as “Lakshmikant/resting on Anantasheshnag in the ocean of milk”,is it addressed to the Lord who is in the bubble(universe)?

Is there any other Lord Vishnu?
Who among these 2 (or 3) is part of the Trimurti?

When a common bhakt adores Lord Vishnu as “Narayan”,whom among the three is he addressing?

(Please also provide an explanation and description of the 2/3 Lord Vishnus)

Comment: The central one is not lord vishnu, he is Mahavishnu. The rest, I am not sure. (Whenever maha is attached it's not the same deity, e.g. Mahalakshmi or Mahasarswati are not the same as Lakshmi or sarswati) But I guess, the one part of trimurti is Mahavishnu. And Narayan would probably refer to Vishnu.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30036/which-all-sects-accept-three-forms-of-vishnu-as-described-in-satvata-tantra) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29173/which-scriptures-mention-the-garbhodakshayi-and-karanodakshayi-forms-of-lord-vis/29185#29185)

Comment: This picture can be found in the books by Srila Prabhupada, a Gaudiya Vaishnava (GV) acarya of ISKCON. I can briefly explain the pic according to the GV doctrine. *From what I have heard,this is a depiction of how innumerable Universes are ... when He inhales.* -- Yes, that is correct. But GV's do not call that Lord as "central Lord Vishnu" but Lord Maha Vishnu. He always, eternally, rests in the causal ocean (the ocean is called like that, "causal", because from it innumerable material universes are created or caused) in the eternal Vaikuntha world above the material worlds. ...

Comment: ... As you can see at the pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MrMJ.jpg Lord Garbhodakashayi Vishnu rests on the Lord Ananta (huge snake, also Lord Vishnu himself) in the bubbles, ie universes, on the oceans in each bubble, ie in each universe. While He rests like that He is served by the goddess Lakshmi, his eternal spouse. The goddess and Lord Ananta can be also seen in each bubble (universe) on the picture. -- *Is there any other Lord Vishnu?* -- ...

Comment: ... Ksirodakashayi Vishnu is the Lord who resides in the hearts of all living beings as a four hand form of Lord Vishnu. He is also referred to as Paramatma or Supersoul. His personal abode is said to be Kshirasagara (Milk Ocean). -- *Who among these is part of the Trimurti?* -- I would say Garbhodakashayi Vishnu is that one who is one of the trimurtis, also possibly Ksirodakashayi Vishnu. Both can be. By the way Lord Vishnu is the Lord, regardless of which one. ...

Comment: ... *When a common bhakt adores Lord Vishnu as “Narayan”,whom among the three is he addressing?* -- All forms of Lord Vishnu, even Lord Krishna, etc, can be called as Lord Narayana. There are several meanings to the name Narayana which are derived from Sanskrit etymology. You can read about that at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana#Nomenclature_and_etymology

Comment: @ Brahma jijnasa You have spoken well...

Comment: This Q should be reopen. It's not duplicate of the linked one!